# Why does a black bar appear when I change the transparency of a span tag?

Tags: html, css

Gave a span tag two backgrounds, then used rgba to make it transparent, but when I change it, a horizontal black strip/bar appears in my content. Can someone explain why, or how to fix it?

Thank you.

```css
h1 span {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    background:  rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="images/castle.jpeg" alt="Wide musuem"/>
  <h1><span>Beautiful Museums<span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: where is ur code?

Comment: If its a mystery to you, then its a mystery to us until you share some code.

Comment: It would be much easier for us to offer solution after seeing problem instead of imaging it.

Comment: Sorry. Submitted question when I wasnt done, have edited and included code.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close your span tag

```
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code. You have two unclosed `<span>`s. Close it:

```css
h1 span {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    background:  rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="images/castle.jpeg" alt="Wide musuem"/>
    <h1><span>Beautiful Museums</span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must close the `span` tag. Instead of

```
<span>Beautiful Museums<span>
```

you must use

```
<span>Beautiful Museums</span>
```

Comment: My apologies. I will look at my spelling before posting again. Thank you.